# Basic CSS: When applying effects to images in CSS, how do you exclude the banner image?

Tags: html, css, web

I have this bit of CSS that results in images popping out a bit when the you hover over them:

```
a img 
{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover img 
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -o-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The problem is that this applies to all images, including my banner. Is there anyway to exclude the banner image?

Comment: Thanks everyone, all your answers have been helpful. I decided to go ahead with :not() for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can reference that banner image with a class or id, and you're okay with spurning your IE8 users, the CSS3 selector `:not()` could work wonders.

[A jsfiddle for you to look at](http://jsfiddle.net/u5pqd/).
[An update to the above Fiddle that's a bit more complex](http://jsfiddle.net/u5pqd/1/).

Besides IE8, [every other major browser, and IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20selector), have support for this.  Firefox and Safari support go back as far as version 1, assuming [this site](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not) is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Reference all hover images with a class name. That will separate them from images that do not have a class.

Ex:

```
<img class="hoverme" src=".." />
<img class="hoverme" src=".." />
<img src=".." />

.hoverme:hover{
  ..
}
```

Only images with hoverme class will be effected.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it's not very elegant-looking. If your banner has an `id`, just override those attributes (hopefully I know what I'm doing):

```
a img#banner
{
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

a:hover img#banner
{
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```